# Controller for partial views ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've just recently started to build a web site using ASP.NET - MVC 4, and Im trying to wrap my head around how this works.

There are some data I would like to display on every page and have understood that Partial Views are great for this.

Is it possible to create a controller that always provides data for the partial view? Or how can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's called a child action.

Call `Html.Action(...)`.

Comment: Will that generate an extra request?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a controller action for the partial view. But if you are looking for inlcluding some thing on every page, you should think about adding that to your _Layout.cshtml page

You can create a normal action method which returns a partial view like this

```
public ActionResult UserInfo()
{
  UserViewModel objVm=GetUserInf();
  //  do some stuff

 return View("PartialUserInfo",objVM);

}
```

This will return a view with name "`PartialUserInfo`" present in your `Views/Users` folder( Assuming your controller name is Users. If you want to specify a view which is a different location you can mention it when calling the View method

```
returnView("Partial/UserInfo",objVm);
```

This will return a View called "UserInfo" in your `Views/Users/Partial` folder.

in your partial view, you can disable the normal layout( if you have one) by doint this

```
@model UserViewModel 
@{
  Layout=null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a model for the parent view (the one hosting all the partials) that contains the models for the partial views as properties on its model

EX:

```
MainModel.ModelForPArtialView1
MainModel.ModelForPArtialView2
MainModel.ModelForPArtialView3
```

That way you can do this on the parent view

```
@Html.Partial("PartialView1",MainModel.ModelForPArtialView1)
@Html.Partial("PartialView2",MainModel.ModelForPArtialView2)
@Html.Partial("PartialView3",MainModel.ModelForPArtialView3)
```

Comment: The solution is also dependent on whether or not the content changes across views. Is the content of the partial exactly the same across all parent views?